# Scroll Controller error when you scroll in page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So, I have menu in my App with category and list of meals. But when I scroll on this page it gives me an error from title. AND IT GIVES THIS ERROR:

```
The PrimaryScrollController is currently attached to more than one С.
```

[Page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY17v.png)

```
CupertinoScrollbar _buildBody() {
    return CupertinoScrollbar(
      child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemScrollController: _itemScrollController,
        itemPositionsListener: _itemPositionsListener,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: Dummy.categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              CustomTextWidget(
                paddingTop: 16,
                paddingLeft: 16,
                paddingBottom: 16,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                text: Text(
                  Dummy.categories.elementAt(index),
                  style: AppConstants.textStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),
                ),
              ),
              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child:
                          isExpanded ? const ExpandedProductCard() : const ProductCard()),
                  const ProductCard(),
                  const ProductCard(),
                  const ProductCard(),
                  const ProductCard(),
                ],
              ),
              Container()
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

And thats a code from CustomTextWidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Alignment? alignment;
  final Widget? text;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final double paddingTop;
  final double paddingBottom;
  final double paddingRight;
  final double paddingLeft;
  const CustomTextWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.alignment,
    this.width,
    @required this.text,
    this.height,
    this.paddingTop = 0,
    this.paddingBottom = 0,
    this.paddingRight = 0,
    this.paddingLeft = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: paddingTop,
        bottom: paddingBottom,
        right: paddingRight,
        left: paddingLeft,
      ),
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Align(
        alignment: alignment ?? Alignment.center,
        child: text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried lots of solutions but it's always gives me same error(
Help me to solve this, so I can normally scroll in App

Comment: share the code from CustomTextWidget

Comment: Try to Dispose the _itemScrollController

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the

> CustomTextWidget

with a Container widget and set the height explicitly:

```
Container(
  height: 40,
  child: CustomTextWidget(
    paddingTop: 16,
```